# Wordpress how to redirect url

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect user to home page when he just enters on the website. For example typing www.website.com need redirect to www.website.com/home

I trued to redirect using

```
header("Location: www.example.com/home");
```

bu it didn't work what are other methods to do it and not using any wp plugin for this?

Comment: Why don't you choose the home page in the Wordpress settings and it will automatically go to that page? Its rather unusual to need to redirect to your homepage in the code. If you let us know the reason you want to do it that way, we might have a better solution.

Comment: Prefer to use wordpress settings, rather than writing PHP snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Settings` > `Reading` in your Admin Dashboard.
Then, under `Front page displays`, click on `A static page` and select your page which you want as front page.

Answer (score 0):

try this :- wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/home' );

Answer (score 0):

Use template redirect hook and for redirects.
place below code in your themes function.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mytheme_redirect' );

function mytheme_redirect(){
    // Your code
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
}
```

Comment: This is needed only if you need redirects, to set a static page as home page  go to Admin Dashboard => Settings => Reading => Front page displays, click on a static page and select your page which you want as homepage.